# Non-existence of local generators for Sobolev tangent subundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded open set, a rank $r\le n$ measurable tangent subbundle $\mathcal V$ on $U$ is a map to the Grassmannian $\mathcal V:U\to Gr(r,\mathbb R^n)$ which is only defined almost everywhere.

For a compact metric space $N$ the fractional $L^2$-Sobolev class  $H^\frac12(U;N)$ is the space of all $f:U\to N$ such that $$\int_{U\times U}\frac{\operatorname{dist}(f(x),f(y))^2}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dxdy<\infty.$$

My **question** is, can we find a subbundle $\mathcal V:U\to Gr(r,\mathbb R^n)$ (for some $n$ and $r$), such that it has no orthnormal frame with $H^\frac12$-coefficients near the origin?

In other words, for this $\mathcal V$, we cannot find a neighborhood $U'\subset U$ of $0$ and $X_1,\dots,X_r\in H^\frac12(U';\mathbb R^n)$ such that $X_i(x)\cdot X_j(x)=\delta_{ij}$ for almost every $x\in U'$ and $X_1(x),\dots,X_r(x)$ span $\mathcal V(x)$ for almost every $x\in U'$.